# Getting ID of Sitecore control from controller

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to get a field value associated with a control instance in Sitecore within an MVC controller.  I seem to be struggling to find the correct syntax.

I tried this I tried using this within the Sitecore controls MVC controller, but it comes back with a null reference exception for "Item":

```cs
Guid campaignID = new Guid(Constants.Marketing.CAMPAIGNID);
Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext renderingContext = new Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext();
string currentCampaign = renderingContext.PageContext.Item.Fields[campaignID.ToString()].Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a new instance of `RenderingContext` class.

You should use `RenderingContext.Current`. Try the code below:

```cs
Item datasourceOrContextItem = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
string currentCampaign = datasourceOrContextItem[campaignID.ToString()].
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for controllers to have a base controller like below :

```
  public class ControllerBase : Controller
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current rendering.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The Sitecore controller rendering.
    /// </value>
    protected virtual Rendering Rendering
    {
        get
        {
            return RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull != null ? RenderingContext.Current.Rendering : null;
        }
    }
  }
```

When you create a new controller inherits from it and you will have on Rendering, datasource of the item.